# Do charges' sign are conventional?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, coulombs-law, elementary-particles

As we know in the universe there are two types of charges, positive for some elementary particles and negative for other. By inversion charge sign of elementary particles the world be the same this couldn't affect some physical phenomena. If not, so the charge signs just hold the information that only exist two kind of electricity.

Comment: Ben Franklin assigned them. Yes, there are two signs. So?

Comment: I meant if the sign of the particle charge reflect any intrinsic property !

Comment: The choosing of electrons to be labelled "negative" and protons "positive", for instance, is completely arbitrary, if that's what you're getting at.

Comment: It is interesting to see the consequences of the sign charge also in electromagnetism. The concept of electric current is affected directly by the the charge sign and this is why  the physicists made the conventional direction of electron current. Thank you for the link, it was informative for me. But I don't grasp the idea about charge colors, the electric force has to do with the nucleons cohesion ?? .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at Coulomb's law (leaving out constants):

$$F \propto \frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2}$$

If we were to invert the sign of the charges, we'd get

$$F \propto \frac{(-q_1)(-q_2)}{r^2} = \frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2}$$

The two minus signs just cancel each other!

That means, wherever two charges interact, only the relative sign between the two charges is important. The sign of the individual charges is purely conventional.

Comment: That's what I thought, really it still conventional.